# How to prevent network outages caused by renewal of DHCP leasing?

Tags: networking, dhcp, ping, network-adapter

Lease expiration time of DHCP server on my **Mikrotik RB951G-2HnD** router is currently set to 10 minutes:

[image]

So every 10 minutes, the following outage happens on the network adapter:

```
2017-06-08  0:10:52,33 Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=64
2017-06-08  0:10:53,36 Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
2017-06-08  0:10:54,38 Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
2017-06-08  0:10:55,41 Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
2017-06-08  0:10:56,44 Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
2017-06-08  0:10:57,46 Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=64
2017-06-08  0:10:58,49 Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
2017-06-08  0:10:59,58 PING: transmit failed. General failure. 
2017-06-08  0:11:01,33 PING: transmit failed. General failure. 
2017-06-08  0:11:02,35 PING: transmit failed. General failure. 
2017-06-08  0:11:03,37 PING: transmit failed. General failure. 
2017-06-08  0:11:04,39 PING: transmit failed. General failure. 
2017-06-08  0:11:05,49 General failure.
2017-06-08  0:11:06,67 General failure.
2017-06-08  0:11:07,70 Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
2017-06-08  0:11:08,72 Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
2017-06-08  0:11:09,75 Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
2017-06-08  0:11:10,77 Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
2017-06-08  0:11:11,80 Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
2017-06-08  0:11:12,82 Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=64
2017-06-08  0:11:13,86 Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
2017-06-08  0:11:14,89 Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
2017-06-08  0:11:15,91 Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
```

This breaks my VPN connection or downloads or similar activities.

How to fix the problem?

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr** [Reset the TCP/IP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/299357/how-to-reset-tcp-ip-by-using-the-netshell-utility) using `netsh int ip reset` and restart the computer

---

Outages shown above are caused by expired DHCP leasing of IP address. This was verified by changing of lease time on DHCP server. Frequency of outages started copying new interval. So when leasing expires, there is series of general failures (in repeated `ping` command or elsewhere) until new lease of IP address is retrieved.

But on healthy computer, lease of IP address typically does not expire. Command `ipconfig /all | find "Lease"` lists expiration times which can be seen **automatically prolonged** if remaining lease time drops below 50%. So if DHCP server gives 10 minute leases, prolongation should be seen as soon as there is less than 5 minutes left. This way, lease time should never be exhausted. So this early renewal prevents general failures visible in the question. This is the first part of the answer: **lease time expirations should not happen without reason**.

Why leases fully expire on problematic computer?

DHCP server shows every renewal as expected. Even a renewal for problematic computer is issued early enough. But such renewal is not reflected in the computer as it should be. Let's check that. What happens in the computer when we ask for renewal manually using `ipconfig /renew`?

Command `ipconfig /renew` returns error

> An error occured while renewing interface *[interface name here]* : unable to contact your DHCP server. Request has timed out.

But we already know that DHCP server is available. Command `ipconfig /release & ipconfig /renew` renews the lease normally. So why `ipconfig /renew` without prior `ipconfig /release` leads to error?

[This seems to be internal problem of TCP/IP in Windows.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-networking/unable-to-contact-your-dchp-server/353f3f63-d1a6-4606-bad4-621a5649b738) The solution of [resetting TCP IP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/299357/how-to-reset-tcp-ip-by-using-the-netshell-utility) and restarting the computer worked for me. Now the computer is renewing the lease early, as it should (at 50% of lease time) and connection is stable, without outages from expired leases.